# What are volume servers?

Tags: hosting, datacenter

I am currently reading a lot literature about data centers. I often read the term "volume server" which seem to be some kind of standard server that we can rent today.

However, I am not really sure if I know what exactly is referred to and I would be happy if someone could point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volume servers are normally referred to as 1 Server = 1 Role. Low Volume is normally 1 Server = Many Roles (Normally a Virtual Server).  The term is normally used in design of Datacentre’s to the amount of rack space you would need to complete a function and as a single server performing 1 role takes up more space and power than a Low volume server taking circa the same amount of power but performing more roles these are the more welcomed in most modern datacentre designs.